SwiftUI ShareLink with custom type implementation issues
I am trying to use ShareLink on the latest and greatest Xcode and iOS versions to share a custom type - here are some details:
struct transferTemplate: Codable, Transferable {
var name: String = "The Name"
var words: [String] = ["word1","word2"]

    static var transferRepresentation: some TransferRepresentation {
        CodableRepresentation(contentType: .templatesession)
    }

}

extension UTType {
static var templatesession: UTType = UTType(exportedAs: "com.overload.template")
}

I have my Exported Type Declaration as follows:
<key>UTExportedTypeDeclarations</key>     `
<array>     
<dict>     
<key>UTTypeConformsTo</key>     
<array>     
<string>public.json</string>     
</array>     
<key>UTTypeDescription</key>     
<string>Template Session</string>     
<key>UTTypeIconFiles</key>     
<array/>     
<key>UTTypeIdentifier</key>     
<string>com.overload.template</string>     
<key>UTTypeTagSpecification</key>     
<dict>     
<key>public.filename-extension</key>     
<array>     
<string>templatesession</string>     
</array>     
<key>public.mime-type</key>     
<array/>     
</dict>     
</dict>     
</array>`


And my Bundle Document Types as follows:
<key>CFBundleDocumentTypes</key>     
<array>     
<dict>     
<key>CFBundleTypeName</key>     
<string>Template Session</string>     
<key>LSHandlerRank</key>     
<string>Owner</string>     
<key>LSItemContentTypes</key>     
<array>     
<string>com.overload.template</string>     
</array>     
</dict>     
<dict/> 
</array>

I am able to share an example using the following simple setup (declared in their proper context):
@State private var transferred: transferTemplate = transferTemplate(name: "NameTemplate", words: \["One","Two"\])

ShareLink(item: transferred, preview: SharePreview("Share your lift", image: Image("tanLogo")))

Using the above ShareLink I can send my custom file type through iMessage, but when I tap on the link it doesn't open my app, it opens a json viewer and shows me the raw json. I have the following set up to handle the URL:
WindowGroup {       
ContentView()         
    .onOpenURL(perform: { url in             
    print("process URL")         
    }) 
}

I can save the file from messages into my iPhone files, then open it manually in my app and will see "process URL" in the console. I feel like I've logically set this up properly and I have an issue in my PLIST configuration, but I'm at a loss for what to try next. Thank you for your help!
I tried to change Document Type - Handler Rank to Default, expecting manually assigning Owner was an issue. It did not change the outcome.
I tried adjusting Exported Type Identifiers - Description, Conforms To (tried public.content, public.data at the same time, but not one at a time), Mime Types. None of these adjustments made the file open my app automatically and execute the onOpenUrl functionality.
I also added "LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace" to my PLIST with a value of YES as suggested in this thread that I also found helpful but didn't answer my questions: SwiftUI ShareLink share custom data
